# How to remove azure snapshots (Restore points)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine

I'm a lone dev that inherited a giant undocumented mess of an azure vm without any sysadmin-like training nor a lab to test things out. This vm runs our website just fine, but I couldn't log in to VestaCp because disk space usage is at 100%.

I did setup azure to make daily backups. Now I'm wondering if azure somehow stores them on the same machine e.g. they're the cause of the full disk space.
if so, how do I remove a set of old backups?

Comment: I just realised I should probably have posted this in superuser, I apolagise.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using Azure in ARM mode. Are you using Azure Recovery Services for daily backups? If yes then you can access all your backups either from Powershell or Azure Portal. To remove all VM backups use PS cmdlet Disable-`AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -RemoveRecoveryPoints`

Comment: @TomaszTuczapski Can you show me how to remove backups via the azure portal? I've looked everywhere but I can't find the button to remove them. I also just want to remove a few.

Comment: You could follow this two tutorials ([VM classic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-manage-vms-classic), [VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-manage-vms)) to manage your VM backups via azure portal.

Comment: Ok, that's what I needed, many thanks @Bruce-MSFT

Comment: Just want to know whether you have solved this issue. Any concerns, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I'm wondering if azure somehow stores them on the same machine e.g. they're the cause of the full disk space.

As mentioned in the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-first-look-arm#create-a-recovery-services-vault-for-a-vm) about creating a recovery services vault for a VM:

> The location of Recovery Services vault determines the geographic region where your backup data is sent.
>
> If you have virtual machines in multiple regions, create a Recovery Services vault in each region.
>
> **There is no need to specify the storage accounts used to store the backup data**--the Recovery Services vault and the Azure Backup service automatically handle the storage.

Per my understanding, your VM backup data could be stored on the storage accounts that are managed automatically by the Recovery Services vault (ARM) and the Azure Backup service (ASM).

Moreover, if this issue could not be solved by removing a set of old backups, I assumed that you could follow this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/madan/2015/11/02/resizing-azure-vm-os-or-data-disk/) to resize Azure VM OS or Data Disk created using Azure Service Manager (ASM) or this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/madan/2016/09/28/resize-azure-resource-manager-arm-vm-os-data-disk-using-azure-portal/) for resizing ARM VM OS & Data disk.